# Is there a way to convert kriged surface to a raster object for clipping? Krige generated from- krige {gstat}

Tags: interpolation

I want to clip krige surface with a shapefile. I think the easiest way would be to rasterize and then to clip but couldn't rasterize the krige surface. Can anyone provide any suggestions?

Comment: what software are you using? What have you tried?

Comment: @RobertHijmans   I am using Rstudio. Krige object was created using krige {gstat} (rpubs.com/nabilabd/118172) which created the output in vector form but I want to clip it to my desired study sites location and I have used the following command for rasterizing the krige object: ( mgimond.github.io/Spatial/interpolation-in-r.html#kriging ) which did not work. # Convert kriged surface to a raster object for clipping r <- raster(dat.krg) r.m <- mask(r, W)

Comment: please edit your question to show what you have done, if at all possible with some example data (see R help files, or most R questions on this site)